# Why is my iPhone prompting me to install an update meant for iPhone XS?

Tags: iphone, software-update

I am using an iPhone 7 in Turkey. My iPhone is prompting me to install a software update which appears to be meant for iPhone XS.

Is this normal? I just want to make sure my iPhone isn't hacked and is behaving as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an indication of an hacked iPhone at all.

The screenshot contains a description of the bugfixes included in a new iOS update from Apple. You do not get a personal description of only the changes that are important to you, rather they write one description that everyone gets.

For example: If you happen to be using an iPhone XR in Turkey, this change is important to you. If you don't - just ignore it.

In general updates could contain more fixes than the ones that are explicitly highlighted, so you'll want to install them even though the explicitly detailed ones aren't applicable to you.

Comment: Also, if you scroll down the message you get a link to the security related content of the update which probably (I didn't read it before the upgrade) is relevant for all iOS devices running iOS 12.

Comment: Up until a few days ago, I always got update details about iphone 7, united states version. So this is new to me.

Comment: @DanRan No, it is not new. It has always been like this, and for all users around the world. There has newer been a specific message for iPhone 7 holders in the US. However, other update versions hasn't had specific features for Turkey or iPhone XS highlighted, so you might have mistakenly thought that these update descriptions were specifically tailored for you personally. They're not.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would this also be the same for an iphone for the federal government or employees of the federal government?

Comment: Yes. It is the same.